# What is the difference between %{[field]} and [field] in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

could someone tell me what difference is there between you use my field in these two ways? Modify the data type?

Answer (score 1):

In some places %{[field]} can be used to reference the contents of the field. For example

```
input { generator { count => 1 lines => [ '' ] } }
filter {
    mutate { add_field => { "[Field1]" => "1" } }
    mutate { rename => { "[Field1]" => "[Field2]" } }

    mutate { add_field => { "[Field3]" => "3" } }
    mutate { add_field => { "[Field4]" => "4" } }
    mutate { rename => { "[Field3]" => "%{[Field4]}" } }
}
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => false } } }
```

will produce

```
         "4" => "3",
    "Field2" => "1",
```

The first pair of mutates adds a field called [Field1], and then renames it to [Field2]. The second set of mutates renames [Field3] based on the contents of [Field4].

This is called a [sprintf](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#sprintf) reference. It does not work everywhere. It requires the plugin to [sprintf](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-mutate/blob/9d691111049a10e45d83155497eb8a6778aa3f45/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb#L284) the reference and the code does not always do that in places you would expect.